# retrieving image from sdcard in android

Tags: android, image, file, android-intent, start-activity

in my android application, when i click on button new activity starts and retrieves image info from sdcard n display it.when i click one of thumbnail of image i want to send that image to 1st activity.how can i do this using startactivityforresult.how to store image path and send it back to 1st activity.i want array for storing uri off all images as i'm listing them dynamically

in 1st activty-

```
  public void importFile(View v){

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,ImportFile.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        String path=data.getDataString();

    }
}
```

2nd activity-

```
 int j=0;
  File[] imagefile;
 File f = new File("/sdcard");
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file1 = files[i];
         imagefile[j]=file1; //here getting  nullpointer exception
             }
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int j;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(j=1;j<idcount;j++){
            if(ch[j].isChecked())
            {
                System.out.println("PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP"+j);
                i=new Intent();
                i.putExtra("file","mmm");//here how can i send image path
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Depends of your way to get your image from sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set the file name in the extras try retrieving it back from the extras..

String path= data.getStringExtra("file");

Comment: hoe can i store path. i used File[] imagefile; imagefiles[id]=file1; where, File f = new File("/sdcard");
         File[] files = f.listFiles(); File file1 = files[1];

Comment: This should works:     
      String imagePath = imagefiles[id].getAbsolutePath();
      Intent resultData = new Intent();
      resultData.putExtra("imagePath", imagePath);
      setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
      finish();

Answer (score 0):

Supose you retrieves the image from sdcard in your Import.java Acitivty like that:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "MyFile.jpg");
```

So, once you have your image in a File object, you just need to put its path on a Intent that will be used to be a result data, which will be sent back to the "caller" activity. In some point of your "called" acitivity you should do that:

```
 Intent resultData = new Intent();
 resultData.putExtra("imagePath", file.getAbsolutePath());
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();
```

Your method onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if(requestCode==RESULT_OK)
   {
       String path = data.getStringExtra("imagePath");           

   }
```

}

That's it!

Comment: i'm retriving images.not single image.how can i store all path

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894644/storing-image-path-from-sdcard-in-android/14894934#14894934 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer:

By using this you can fetch images from Gallery and put it on the imageview or arraylist of uri. Here filepath is your selected photo image path from sd card. You can directly add this into your array list of Uri. or you can set image as a bitmap using image.setImageBitmap();

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK , android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    YourActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent,SELECT_PICTURE);
```

onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String filePath;
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult,requestCode" + requestCode);

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            try {
                System.out.println("I ma here1");

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                Log.i(TAG, "======gallery image path=======:" + filePath);
                // ======gallery image path=======:/mnt/sdcard/wallpaper4.jpg

                // imageViewPhoto.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                cursor.close();
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = null;
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                image_sublable.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yourSelectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
                image = os.toByteArray();
                imagefilePath = filePath;
                Log.i(TAG, "image in method=>" + image);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

You can directly add file path in string and store it into String array. Try using this and get some idea.

```
 int j=0;
      String[] imagefile = new String[]{};
           String fileString = filePath; // copy file path into fileString
            String[] files = f.listofString();
          for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                String fileString = files[i];
             imagefile[j]=fileString; //here getting  nullpointer exception
                 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: how can i set path of File type in Uri array.see the code in 2nd activity

Comment: check my edited answer above for the 2nd Activity. and I think you got null pointer exception because you have declare size of Array.

Comment: If you got my answer is useful then check upvote and make it right if it solve you error below upvote.