# storing image path from sdcard in android

Tags: android, image, file, android-intent

how to store image path into array.as i'm retrieving images dynamically.n listing them.after clicking on one o the image i want to send it to previous activity.
how can i store the image path??please help me

```
below is code-
```

1st activity-
    public void importFile(View v){

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,ImportFile.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        String path=data.getDataString();
        System.out.println(";;;;;;;;;;;;"+path);
    }
}
```

2nd activity-

```
in oncreat-
 int j=0;
File[] imagefile;
 File f = new File("/sdcard");
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++,j++) {
            File file1 = files[i];
             if(myfile.endsWith(".jpeg")){
                image[j]=file1;//here i'm getting nullpointer exception
            }
           }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int j;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(j=1;j<idcount;j++){
            if(ch[j].isChecked())
            {
                imagesPaths.add(image[++j].getAbsolutePath());

                i=new Intent();
                i.putExtra("files",imagesPaths);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me see if am i understading. You have a set of image each one represent by a checkbutton, and you intent to send back the paths of selected images. Is it?

Comment: yeah.i want to do the same.for that i have to store images path

Comment: now, the problem is that you are not instantiating the array image.
Change your array declaration: 
From: File[] image; -> To: File[] image = new File[files.lenght];

Answer (score 0):

Using GSON library

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

you can create a json **string** of the image path array then store the json string to preference

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html

Storing value in preference can be accessible to all the activities. And from another activity convert json string to array and you can use that array.

**OR**

You can create a static array in an activity and can use it statically across the activities.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

Your Called Activity:

```
File f = new File("/sdcard");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
ArrayList<String> imagesPaths = new ArrayList<String>(); // Array to store the images paths



@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    i=new Intent();
    for(int j=0; j< ch.lenght; j++){
        if(ch[j].isChecked())
        {
             imagePaths.add(f[j].getAbsolutePath());
        }       
    }
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("files", imagePaths);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

Your Caller Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if(requestCode==1)
   {
       ArrayList<String> paths= data.getStringArrayListExtra("files");
       System.out.println(paths.toString());
  }
```

}

Comment: i did the same.but getting nullpointer exception after checking image type i'm storing image path to another file array.i have updated my code.see that

Comment: you should ensure that the ch array has the correct size, i.e, the same size of files array. Where exactly are you getting a nullPointerException?

Comment: yeah.there is no problem of array size of ch n file array.hoe can i store file to file array.its giving null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

```
case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String path = getRealPathFromURI( selectedImage );
                LogMsg.d("PAth "+path);
                Bitmap b = getBitmap(path);
                bitmapList.add(b);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        break;
```

and then;

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
           ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
           String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
           Cursor cursor = resolver.query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
           int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
```